# Can't connect to redis after upgrading ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

I'm trying to upgrade my app to Mongoid 3 and ruby 1.9.3. I was on 1.9.2 before. My app also uses Redis as a temp data store. No code changes have occurred and this was working fine before... now I'm getting the following error when I run the task that connects to Redis:

```
Can't assign requested address - connect(2)
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:113:in `connect_nonblock'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:113:in `connect'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:170:in `connect'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:257:in `establish_connection'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:63:in `connect'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `ensure_connected'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:167:in `block in process'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:242:in `logging'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:166:in `process'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:78:in `call'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis.rb:912:in `block in rpop'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis.rb:911:in `rpop'
/Users/kevin/myapp/app/models/tweet.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in load_from'
/Users/kevin/myapp/app/models/tweet.rb:33:in `times'
/Users/kevin/myapp/app/models/tweet.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in load_from'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:959:in `call'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:959:in `block in run_deferred_callbacks'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:956:in `times'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:956:in `run_deferred_callbacks'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.rc.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/Users/kevin/myapp/app/models/tweet.rb:30:in `load_from'
/Users/kevin/myapp/lib/tasks/tweet.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/kevin/myapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => tweet:load
```

My Redis is running and I checked the port #.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Redis 3.0.1? Try using Redis 2.2.2